# MySQL decimal column precision with Servicestack ORMLite

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I've got a decimal attribute and I'm trying to set the precision and scale to be 12 and 2 respectively.

My understanding is that I should just be able to do this by adding the DecimalLength attribute to the property like so:

```
[DecimalLength(12,2)]
public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
```

However when the column gets created, it's always created as (38,6). Looking at MySqlDialectProvider.cs, it looks like it never uses those values and always uses (38, 6). Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just added support for custom decimal precision for MySql [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/01bbd3504c65d5557d0554f7eaf5b56caf2ce04b).

This change is available from **v4.0.37+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).